# Android - Zoom in/out from multiple ImageViews

Tags: android, imageview, zooming

Im working on a application that should be able to have diffrent ImageViews applied to a view or layout and zoom in and out from them. Similair to create a chessboard where each square represent a ImageView and then I can zoom out or in from the whole chessboard.

I want to chose a particular ImageView and then add a tween animation to it like a bounce or scaling.

Whats the best approch to do this in Android?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need to check which image is focused. To check this you can try :
    Image focusedImg = getViewById(R.id.YourMainLayout).findFocus();

Now, once you have the focused image you need to apply tween animations on it. Follow the below mentioned link to apply twwen animation :

```
http://chengalva.com/dnn_site/Home/tabid/41/EntryId/57/Android-Tween-Animations.aspx
```

Best,

Shraddha